# Process Hacker/Explorer: How to automatically open process properties on launch

Tags: windows, task-manager, process-explorer

When monitoring/debugging executables, I often have to restart them.

In Process Hacker/Process Explorer: Is it possible to automatically open the properties window after launching/restarting a process (for individual executables)?

Alternatively, is there a way to open/refresh the properties window for processes/executables for which a properties window is already open?

Comment: No it is not possible. The `PID` changes so the data in the old "Properties" dialog is no longer valid.

Comment: Sure, but would it be possible to open a new windows automatically based on the executable's name? (of course, only optionally)

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, after all it is [open source](http://sourceforge.net/p/processhacker/code/HEAD/tree/). Or you could make a [feature request](http://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewforum.php?f=14)